# HTML Form Action - "Order of Operation"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an HTML form on my site that submits via Ajax to a php file after it is validated using jQuery. Here's the opening form tag:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
```

I was thinking of putting the path_to_process_file.php in the form `action` (as seen below) so that if they have JavaScript disabled in their browser, they will still be able to fill out and submit the form.

```
<form action="../path_to_process_file.php" method="post">
```

**My QUESTION**:

- What contents 'order of operations' files should contain ,when submitting a form when JavaScript is ENABLED?
- Will it use the php action path first? Or will it first try submitting through JavaScript?

**UPDATE:
Here's my JS used to submit via Ajax.

```
$( document ).bind( "pageinit", function( event, data ) {
    $("#rackback-quote-request-form").validate({
        // Custom validation messages
        messages: { quote_name: "Please enter your full name."},
        errorElement: "p",
        submitHandler: function(form){

            //Get the data from the form fields and format correctly
            var product = $("#rackback-quote-request-form #product").val();


            var data = 'product=' + product;
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "../php/QR-rackback.php",
              data: data,
              success: function(data) { 
                      $("#rackback-quote-request-wrapper").hide();
                      $("#rackback-quote-request-success").append("<center><h3>Thanks! Your quote request has been sent.</h3></center>" );
                   },
              error: function(){
                  alert("Javascript error, please try again");
              }
            });
            return false;
         }
    });
});
```

Where would I put the  `event.preventDefault();`?**

Comment: Consider using something like `function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }` to halt the general POST; that way you can control the action iff JavaScript is available

Comment: I know just a little of JQuery (I use MooTools), but I think you should do the event.preventDefault() at the beginning of the script. In the case of MooTools, that method prevents the default action of an event, not hindering in any way the following actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your JS will need to attach to the submit event.  In that event, you can prevent it from doing what it would naturally do, like this:

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // use jQuery's ajax() method here to do what you want
});
```

Comment: If you already hooked to the `submit` event, the browser will do both (run the js, then submit normally), unless you use `event.preventDefault()` as this answer suggests.

Comment: Did you pay attention to the second line? If you add event.preventDefault(); you suppress the original HTML action.

Comment: Sorry I missed it the first time... I updated my code at the top. Where would I put the `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: I didn't know you are using validate... that changes things a little bit.  To my knowledge, the submitHandler is already replacing the standard HTML action, so you shouldn't have to add preventDefault at all...  Are you actually experiencing problems with the form submission?  If so, what problems do you encounter?

Comment: I haven't experienced problems as of yet... I just want to know (for future reference) if ALL browsers will default to submitting by JavaScript as I want.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is first executed, and with it you have the possibility to supress the normal (HTML way) of sending the form.

There are many ways to do this depending on the framework you use, but with simple plain JavaScript you can follow these steps:

- Attach a 'onSubmit' event to the form.
- If you want to supress the "normal submission" (HTML way) of the Form, simply **return false**.

Comment: How would you suppress the normal HTML action? In other words, how would I force submitting via Javascript if enabled?

Comment: As I suggested in my answer below, you suppress the normal HTML action in the JS through something like event.preventDefault();